# Integrating Python monorepo application into Yocto

Tags: python, git, yocto, monorepo

A little context before the actual questions. As a project that I have worked on grew, the number of repositories used for the application we're developing grew as well. To the point that it's gotten unbearable to keep making modifications to the codebase: when something is changed in the core library in one repository we need to make adjustments to other Python middleware projects that use this library. Whereas this sounds not that terrifying, managing this in Yocto has become a burden: on every version bump of the Python library we need to bump all of the dependant projects as well. After some thinking, we decided to try a monorepo approach to deal with the complexity. I'm omitting the logic behind choosing this approach but I can delve into it if you think this is wrong.

1) Phase 1 was easy. Just bring every component of our middleware to one repository. Right now we have a big repository with more than git 20 submodules. Submodules will be gone once we finish the transition but as the project doesn't stop while we're doing the transition, submodules were chosen to track the changes and keep the monorepo up to date. Every submodule is a Python code with a setup.py/Pipfile et al. that does the bootstrapping.

2) Phase 2 is to integrate everything in Yocto. It has turned out to be more difficult than I had anticipated.

Right now we have this:

**Application monorepo**

```
Pipfile
python-library1/setup.py
python-library1/Makefile
python-library1/python-library1/<code>


python-library2/setup.py
python-library2/Makefile
python-library2/python-library2/<code>


...
python-libraryN/setup.py
python-libraryN/Makefile
python-libraryN/python-libraryN/<code>
```

Naturally, right now we have `python-library1_<some_version>.bb`, `python-library2_<some_other_version>.bb` in Yocto. Now we want to get rid of this version hell and stick to monorepo versions so that we could have just monorepo_1.0.bb that is to be updated when anything changes in any part.

Right now I have this **monorepo_1.0.bb** (actually, would like to have as this approach doesn't work)

```
SRCREV=<hash>

require monorepo.inc
```

**monorepo.inc** is as follows:

```
SRC_URI=<gitsm://the location of the monorepo,branch=...,>
S = "${WORKDIR}/git"

require python-library1.inc
require python-library2.inc
...
require python-libraryN.inc
```

**python-libraryN.inc:**

```
S = "${WORKDIR}/git/python-libraryN"
inherit setuptools
```

This approach doesn't work for multiple reasons. Basically every new `require` will override `${S}` to another `git/python-library` and the only package that will be built is the last one.

Even though I know that this approach won't end up being the final solution I just wanted to tell you what I've strived for: very easy updates. The only thing that I need to do is just update SRCREV (or ${PV} in the future when this will be deployed) and the whole stack will be brought up to date.

So, well, the question is how to structure the Yocto recipes for Python monorepo manipulation?

P.S. 
1) The monorepo structure is not set in stone so if you have any suggestions, I'm more than open to any criticism
2) The `.inc` file structure might not be suitable for another reason. This stack is deployed across a dozen of different devices and some of those `python-library_N.bb` have `.bbappends` in other layers that are custom for the devices. I mean that some of them might require different components of the system installed or some configs and `files/` modifications.

Any suggestion on how to deal with the complexity of a big Python application in Yocto will be welcome. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently looking into the same issue as you.

I found that the recipe for the `boost` library also builds several packages from a "monorepo".

This recipe can be found in the `poky` layer:
http://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/poky/tree/meta/recipes-support/boost

Look especially into the `boost.inc` file, which builds the actual package list, while the other files define both `SRC_URI` and various patches.

Hope that helps !